# jQuery Pagination working only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I'm using the http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Minimal-jQuery-Table-Pagination-Plugin-SimplePagination.html to paginate a table that changes when I click a button. This button has an Ajax/JSON function "onClick" that appends `<tr>` in this table. The pagination works only on the first time this function is executed, and I already have used .remove() method but It still works once. What do I have to do?

The function that paginates:

```
function paginate(){

$('.pagination').remove();

$("#results").simplePagination({
    perPage: 100,
    containerClass: 'pagination',
    previousButtonClass: "btn btn-danger",
    nextButtonClass: "btn btn-danger"
  });
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT.

the Ajax/Json code:

```
function generateResults(){

$.ajax({
    url:'../json/logs/loadResults.php',
    data:{
      idFolder:idFolder
    },
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data){
        $('#results').show();

        $.each(data, function(){
            $("#results").append("<tr class='tableGrid'><td>"+data[i].id+"</td><td>"+data[i].name+"</td><td>"+data[i].login+"</td><td>"+(data[i].file_create == 1 ? "Yes":"No")+"</td><td>"+(data[i].file_del == 1 ? "Yes":"No")+"</td><td>"+(data[i].file_move == 1 ? "Yes":"No")+"</td><td>"+(data[i].file_rename == 1 ? "Yes":"No")+"</td></tr>");
        i++;
        });

        if($("#results tr").length > 0){
        paginate();
        }
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: call `paginate()` at the end of `Ajax/JSON function "onClick"`?

Comment: Can you include the code that adds the TR element? Does it call the `paginate` function, as Daniel suggested?

Comment: Yes. It does. I made a test, creating a Test Button to Paginate when clicked, erasing the calling at the end of the AJAX/Json, and I got the same result.